# Flash background color of a UITableViewCell on reload

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView in my app. Selecting a cell from the table view adds a subview over top where the user can edit the contents of the table view cell. After the user dismisses the subview, the edited cell is reloaded using the UITableView instance method reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

I want the edited cell to flash it's contentView.background color as an indicator of which cell has just been updated. I know about UITableViewRowAnimation, but it doesn't give me the effect that I want.

Any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `[tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]` unacceptable?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps I'll end up using that, but I would really prefer to have the backgroundColor flash a color of my choice. I also want to be able to control the animation length.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! I was just looking for exactly the opposite, my cell was blinking and after seeing your answer i realised it was because of UITableViewRowAnimationFade.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but I think I found a good way to do this (just grabbing the first cell as an example):

```
NSArray* cells = [self.tableView visibleCells];
UITableViewCell* cell = [cells objectAtIndex:0];
NSIndexPath* path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
{
    UIColor* color = nil;
    if (i % 2 == 0) 
    {
        color = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else 
    {
        color = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
    NSMutableArray* stuff = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
    NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path, nil];
    [stuff addObject:rowsToReload];
    [stuff addObject:color];
    [self performSelector:@selector(flash:) withObject:stuff afterDelay:i * .2];
}
```

And have this method:

```
-(void)flash:(NSMutableArray*)stuff
{
    NSArray* rowsToReload = [stuff objectAtIndex:0];
    self.flashColor = [stuff objectAtIndex:1];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Then, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath (you probably want something after this method which sets the flashColor back to nil):

```
if (self.flashColor != nil) cell.backgroundColor = self.flashColor;
```